# I typoed : instead of = to assign a value to a variable in python. Why didn't this cause a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-typing

In a python project, I came across the following typo that had been lying dormant for a while in the codebase.

```
val1: int = 1
val2: int = 2
dict_x: dict[str, int] = {}
# normal dict assignment.
dict_x["key1"] = val1
# typo!! should surely be a syntax error? instead, a nop (?)
dict_x["key2"]: val2
```

But instead of a syntax error, Python continues silently (and the value of the dict for `"key2"` is not updated). Plugging this code into the python REPL suggests that the line simply returns `None` and moves on, and doesn't modify the dict.

In this case, this behavior (no error occurring) obfuscated a bug that lived in the codebase for a long time.

My suspicion is that this has to do with Python typing, and that this line is being read as a type annotation (and hence, a nop). This explanation only raises more questions, though.

1. How can I guarantee that this is what this syntax is doing? I'm concerned there may be dark python syntax I'm unfamiliar with and this line is performing some task I'm unaware of.
2. Why are type annotations in this case permitted where clearly neither the string `val2` nor the literal number 2 are types?

Comment: That's the syntax to add type annotations. These are basically hints for what types the variables should be. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/ for more info.

Comment: as for part 2, i know that python treats all type annotations as comments, it's up to your IDE/language server (or alternative python implementation) to handle it

Comment: Python will happily run this code, but that's because type hints don't really do anything at _runtime_. However, if you use a static type checker, like [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/), then you will see that mypy complains very loudly about this :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see from the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) that this is legal because the type annotation is only expected to be an expression, and that's very broad:

```
assignment:
    | NAME ':' expression ['=' annotated_rhs ] 
    . . .
```

This syntax has no bearing the runtime of the code. If the "type" is nonsensical, and the warnings/errors produced will be dependent on the linter being used.